# AWS ECS: ecs-agent does not start

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, amazon-ecs, ubuntu-18.04

I am unable to run the ecs-agent properly on my EC2 instance and add it to my ECS cluster.
The ecs-agent logs in `/var/log/ecs/ecs-agent.log` shows:

```
level=info time=2023-07-11T05:44:14Z msg="Successfully got ECS instance credentials from provider: EC2RoleProvider" module=instancecreds_linux.go
level=info time=2023-07-11T05:44:14Z msg="Starting Amazon ECS Agent" version="1.73.1" commit="8b82dfb7"
level=info time=2023-07-11T05:44:14Z msg="Loading configuration"
level=warn time=2023-07-11T05:44:14Z msg="Unable to fetch user data: EC2MetadataError: failed to make EC2Metadata request\n\tstatus code: 404, request id: \ncaused by: <?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"iso-8859-1\"?>\n<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC \"-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN\"\n\t\t \"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd\">\n<html xmlns=\"http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml\" xml:lang=\"en\" lang=\"en\">\n <head>\n  <title>404 - Not Found</title>\n </head>\n <body>\n  <h1>404 - Not Found</h1>\n </body>\n</html>\n" module=config.go
level=info time=2023-07-11T05:44:14Z msg="Successfully got ECS instance credentials from provider: EC2RoleProvider" module=instancecreds_linux.go
level=info time=2023-07-11T05:44:14Z msg="Unable to get Docker client for version 1.17: version detection check: failed to ping with Docker version: 1.17: permission denied while trying to connect to the Docker daemon socket at unix:///var/run/docker.sock: Get \"http://%2Fvar%2Frun%2Fdocker.sock/_ping\": dial unix /var/run/docker.sock: socket: permission denied" module=sdkclientfactory.go
level=info time=2023-07-11T05:44:14Z msg="Unable to get Docker client for version 1.18: version detection check: failed to ping with Docker version: 1.18: permission denied while trying to connect to the Docker daemon socket at unix:///var/run/docker.sock: Get \"http://%2Fvar%2Frun%2Fdocker.sock/_ping\": dial unix /var/run/docker.sock: socket: permission denied" module=sdkclientfactory.go
level=info time=2023-07-11T05:44:14Z msg="Unable to get Docker client for version 1.19: version detection check: failed to ping with Docker version: 1.19: permission denied while trying to connect to the Docker daemon socket at unix:///var/run/docker.sock: Get \"http://%2Fvar%2Frun%2Fdocker.sock/_ping\": dial unix /var/run/docker.sock: socket: permission denied" module=sdkclientfactory.go
level=info time=2023-07-11T05:44:14Z msg="Unable to get Docker client for version 1.20: version detection check: failed to ping with Docker version: 1.20: permission denied while trying to connect to the Docker daemon socket at unix:///var/run/docker.sock: Get \"http://%2Fvar%2Frun%2Fdocker.sock/_ping\": dial unix /var/run/docker.sock: socket: permission denied" module=sdkclientfactory.go
level=info time=2023-07-11T05:44:14Z msg="Unable to get Docker client for version 1.21: version detection check: failed to ping with Docker version: 1.21: permission denied while trying to connect to the Docker daemon socket at unix:///var/run/docker.sock: Get \"http://%2Fvar%2Frun%2Fdocker.sock/_ping\": dial unix /var/run/docker.sock: socket: permission denied" module=sdkclientfactory.go
level=info time=2023-07-11T05:44:14Z msg="Unable to get Docker client for version 1.22: version detection check: failed to ping with Docker version: 1.22: permission denied while trying to connect to the Docker daemon socket at unix:///var/run/docker.sock: Get \"http://%2Fvar%2Frun%2Fdocker.sock/_ping\": dial unix /var/run/docker.sock: socket: permission denied" module=sdkclientfactory.go
level=info time=2023-07-11T05:44:14Z msg="Unable to get Docker client for version 1.23: version detection check: failed to ping with Docker version: 1.23: permission denied while trying to connect to the Docker daemon socket at unix:///var/run/docker.sock: Get \"http://%2Fvar%2Frun%2Fdocker.sock/_ping\": dial unix /var/run/docker.sock: socket: permission denied" module=sdkclientfactory.go
level=info time=2023-07-11T05:44:14Z msg="Unable to get Docker client for version 1.24: version detection check: failed to ping with Docker version: 1.24: permission denied while trying to connect to the Docker daemon socket at unix:///var/run/docker.sock: Get \"http://%2Fvar%2Frun%2Fdocker.sock/_ping\": dial unix /var/run/docker.sock: socket: permission denied" module=sdkclientfactory.go
level=info time=2023-07-11T05:44:14Z msg="Unable to get Docker client for version 1.25: version detection check: failed to ping with Docker version: 1.25: permission denied while trying to connect to the Docker daemon socket at unix:///var/run/docker.sock: Get \"http://%2Fvar%2Frun%2Fdocker.sock/_ping\": dial unix /var/run/docker.sock: socket: permission denied" module=sdkclientfactory.go
level=info time=2023-07-11T05:44:14Z msg="Unable to get Docker client for version 1.26: version detection check: failed to ping with Docker version: 1.26: permission denied while trying to connect to the Docker daemon socket at unix:///var/run/docker.sock: Get \"http://%2Fvar%2Frun%2Fdocker.sock/_ping\": dial unix /var/run/docker.sock: socket: permission denied" module=sdkclientfactory.go
level=info time=2023-07-11T05:44:14Z msg="Unable to get Docker client for version 1.27: version detection check: failed to ping with Docker version: 1.27: permission denied while trying to connect to the Docker daemon socket at unix:///var/run/docker.sock: Get \"http://%2Fvar%2Frun%2Fdocker.sock/_ping\": dial unix /var/run/docker.sock: socket: permission denied" module=sdkclientfactory.go
level=info time=2023-07-11T05:44:14Z msg="Unable to get Docker client for version 1.28: version detection check: failed to ping with Docker version: 1.28: permission denied while trying to connect to the Docker daemon socket at unix:///var/run/docker.sock: Get \"http://%2Fvar%2Frun%2Fdocker.sock/_ping\": dial unix /var/run/docker.sock: socket: permission denied" module=sdkclientfactory.go
level=info time=2023-07-11T05:44:14Z msg="Unable to get Docker client for version 1.29: version detection check: failed to ping with Docker version: 1.29: permission denied while trying to connect to the Docker daemon socket at unix:///var/run/docker.sock: Get \"http://%2Fvar%2Frun%2Fdocker.sock/_ping\": dial unix /var/run/docker.sock: socket: permission denied" module=sdkclientfactory.go
level=info time=2023-07-11T05:44:14Z msg="Unable to get Docker client for version 1.30: version detection check: failed to ping with Docker version: 1.30: permission denied while trying to connect to the Docker daemon socket at unix:///var/run/docker.sock: Get \"http://%2Fvar%2Frun%2Fdocker.sock/_ping\": dial unix /var/run/docker.sock: socket: permission denied" module=sdkclientfactory.go
level=info time=2023-07-11T05:44:14Z msg="Unable to get Docker client for version 1.31: version detection check: failed to ping with Docker version: 1.31: permission denied while trying to connect to the Docker daemon socket at unix:///var/run/docker.sock: Get \"http://%2Fvar%2Frun%2Fdocker.sock/_ping\": dial unix /var/run/docker.sock: socket: permission denied" module=sdkclientfactory.go
level=info time=2023-07-11T05:44:14Z msg="Unable to get Docker client for version 1.32: version detection check: failed to ping with Docker version: 1.32: permission denied while trying to connect to the Docker daemon socket at unix:///var/run/docker.sock: Get \"http://%2Fvar%2Frun%2Fdocker.sock/_ping\": dial unix /var/run/docker.sock: socket: permission denied" module=sdkclientfactory.go
level=error time=2023-07-11T05:44:14Z msg="DockerGoClient: Docker SDK client unable to connect to Docker daemon. Ensure Docker is running: docker client factory: client not found for docker version: 1.21" module=docker_client.go
level=critical time=2023-07-11T05:44:14Z msg="Error creating Docker client" error="docker client factory: client not found for docker version: 1.21"
```

I currently use the AMI `ubuntu/images/hvm-ssd/ubuntu-bionic-18.04-amd64-server-20210224` for this EC2 instance.

docker version: `Docker version 20.10.16, build aa7e414`

I am currently utilizing the machine using `docker-compose` and I want the containers be manged by ECS but I am unable to run the ecs-agent properly.

Comment: Does it have container instance ( ecsInstanceRole) role?

Comment: Yes it has. I also tried adding another instance to my cluster and it works fine. it just not work on this particular instance.